# String Stream is adding a new line when converting an int

Tags: c++, stringstream

I am trying to limit the length of a line to fit on a page nicely and am using the following code

```
 if (!primes[j]) {
    stringstream st;
    st << j;
    test += " "+st.str();
    if (test.length() > 71) {
        cout << line << endl;
        line = st.str();
    } else {
        line += " "+st.str();
    }
    test = line;
}
```

I need to convert the `int j` to a string and add its chars to check if the line will become too long.

Anyways the problem is that my output is always:

```
12522
1548
78455
```

etc..

What is adding these lines?

Comment: it looks like `flush` is adding a newline.  What is `flush`?

Comment: flush was an experiment as I thought possibly by having just st << j; I still got the lines. Flush just clears the buffer.

Comment: It is working now for some reason, maybe my compiler did not make the know file or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flush` there serves to signal end of the output and hence it adds the new line.

Comment: Ya this may have been my problem, thanks a bunch Also thanks to @NathanOliver for pointing it out too. Will accept this soon as I can.